# Spring Security PermissionEvaluator: how to implement hasPermission method with object ID?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

Spring's Security *"hasPermission"* method has an implementation, which (as I get) is intended for passing class name (*targetType*) and Object Id (*Serializable*).

So could you please explain (at least in general) **how to do this implementation right**?
I've searched for example of passing object ID and found no any (even at Spring's doc).

In my situation I want to check for User's `DELETE` permission on some of my classes (for instance, "Goal"). All of these classes has universal methods and fields, so I can have universal logic for checking permission inside a `PermissionEvaluator`.

For doing this I'm intended to pass an Object's ID and Object's class name into PermissionEvaluator and do the check here like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#id, 'Goal','DELETE')")
```

It sounds pretty good till it not comes to the implementation, because I don't really understand how can I get Object's instance by Class name and Id inside Permission evaluator.

```
@Component
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator 

 @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable serializable, String targetType,
                                 Object permission) {
```

Yes, I can instantiate object by `Class.forName(targetType)`, but how can I get it's instance by `Id (serializable)` from appropriate Repository then? (I have different repository for every object). 
`@Autowiring` all of my 30 repositories would be the madness.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented my service, which takes Object ID and Object Type and then sends back Object, which I can later unbox. I used dynamic HQL, so no need in 30+ JPA repositories autowiring (my bad, I missed this possibility at the beginning).

```
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    static String entityClassPath="com.platform.entity.";

    public Object getEntity(String className, Long id) {

        String classToQuery = capitalize(className);

        /* Check if Entity class exists to decide whether to query DB or not */
        try {
            Class cls = Class.forName(entityClassPath + className);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }

        /* Query DB if Entity class exist */
        Query query;
        try {
            query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT Q FROM " + classToQuery + " Q WHERE Q.id=?1");
            query.setParameter(1, id);
            return query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
        }
    }
```